# i am using mysqli statement in procedural php..... data types dont work

Tags: php, mysqli

The column test_int is an `integer` however when I execute the below query it shows successful. 
I wonder how it can be successful because I am entering a string  `$id = "tett";` 
I think it should not execute the query because the data type does not match.

```
<?php


include('db_connect.php');


// Prepare an insert statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO admin (test_int, username, password, maname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql)){
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isss", $id, $username, $password, $maname);

    // Set parameters
    $id = "tett";
    $username = "New username";//$_REQUEST['first_name'];
    $password = "New password";//$_REQUEST['last_name'];
    $maname = "New Name";//$_REQUEST['email'];

    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        echo "Records inserted successfully.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not execute query: $sql. " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . mysqli_error($con);
}

// Close statement
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

// Close connection
mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you specify in `bind_param` is telling PHP what it should cast the value as. 99.99% of the time you should cast it as a string, so that you do not run into issues. If you cast it as an integer [PHP will do the usual casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting). Since `tett` can't be converted into a proper number, PHP will simply convert it into a `0`.

By the way, you must remember to enable error reporting for mysqli. Put this line before `mysqli_connect()`:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

You can also make your code much simpler if you remove all unnecessary stuff.

```
<?php

include 'db_connect.php';

// Prepare an insert statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO admin (test_int, username, password, maname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $id, $username, $password, $maname);

// Set parameters
$id = "tett";
$username = "New username"; //$_REQUEST['first_name'];
$password = "New password"; //$_REQUEST['last_name'];
$maname = "New Name"; //$_REQUEST['email'];

// Attempt to execute the prepared statement
$stmt->execute();
echo "Records inserted successfully.";
```

**Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Comment: What exactly does "ssss" do in this statement?  $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $id, $username, $password, $maname);

Comment: The `ssss` tells mysqli that the values should be bound as strings. Each s is for a single parameter.

Comment: @Paedow nobody called error handling unnecessary, it would be just *misplaced* here. Error handling should be centralized and uniform. Please see [this article](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) and also this [answer of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/243749/101565) that explains why your mysqli code shouldn't  handle its errors to report them.